# How to convert values into Thousands in the Backend

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text box with an extension of thousands.

In the text box the user enters only "7" for 7000 and "10" for 10000 and "75" for 75000. The values of 7000, 10000 has to be stored in our database. How can we do this?

As of Initial step, I have created a normal database connection to store values in the database. My databse will store only values in the format of 7,10,75 as user entered but not of multiplication*1000

But I would like to store it in the form of thousands. Could you let me know how to code this in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Well multiply what the user enters by 1000 when you store the data,

Comment: @GaurangJoshi YUK, thats an ugly idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly although not sure ,  I think he means formatting , something like `str_pad()` or `sprintf()` but your idea is also great :-) ( no smily face adequate for this situation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply it by 1000 while entering.
eq

```
<?php
$number=intval($_POST["number"])*1000;
$sql="insert into database.table values($number)";
//query to database
?>
```

Comment: It worked.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple arithmetic with SQL. When you are inserting, use a query something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (thous_val) VALUES (1000 * ?)
```

where `?` is the value from your form.

Upon retrieval do something like this. Use the integer `DIV` operator or you'll get numbers after the decimal place.

```
SELECT (thous_val DIV 1000) val
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCATENATION while inserting values to table.

Like...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, price) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', '".intval($_POST["price"])*1000."')";
```

Comment: YUK Thats still an ugly idea

Comment: Why in the world would you use concatenation, a string operation, to perform what should be a mathematical operation?